# Geth expose eth.call only via --rpcapi

Tags: go-ethereum

Need a way to open Geth publicly, but don't want to expose all `eth` methods. Need only `eth.call`.

Using `--rpcapi eth` will expose all `eth` methods.
How to expose only particular one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy script to filter the requests and only pass the ones you need to localhost rpc